# Tramp ignores remote paths, no matter what

Tags: tramp, remote

I run Emacs 27.1 in a Windows 10 environment, and I use `tramp` via `plinkx` for remote editing.
I don't have `diff` installed locally, and I don't have the privileges to do it, so I'd like to avail of the one installed in the linux server. I put into my init.el

```
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
```

But when I try to compare two buffers I get:

```
(file-missing "Searching for program" #("No such file or directory" 0 25 (charset windows-1252)) "diff")
call-process("diff" nil #<buffer *ediff-diff*> nil "--binary" "c:/Users/giglida/AppData/Local/Temp/1/responsabile..." "c:/Users/giglida/AppData/Local/Temp/1/responsabile...")
[...]
command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Why does it insist in searching for `diff` locally?

Answer (score 3):

`call-process` runs local processes. For remote processes, you must use `process-file` instead.

Comment: I'm reading the documentation but it's really puzzling. I suppose I have to create an exception for the program diff only.

Comment: If you want to call a program either local or remote, you can always use `process-file`. It supports both cases. If you need a guarantee that the program is called locally only, use `call-process`.

Comment: Dear Michael sorry if I bother you againg but my problem is that the program is invoked via ediff as a frontend, so I cannot figure out where to insert my customization.

Comment: ediff shall be aware of remote processes. Hard to debug via stackexchange, I recommend to contact the Tramp team via `tramp-devel@gnu.org`.